# Simple and secure CMS/Blog add-on for a Codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a custom made codeigniter application, and now I need a CMS/Blog add-on for my site. I don't want to write something like that from the ground up.

I am looking for an open source simple/lightweight and secure CMS/Blog written in codeigniter with the following features:

1) Posts & Page

2) Categories

3) Picture upload in the text-editor

4) Something that does not use HMVC, but a normal codeigniter installation

5) Does not necessarily need user ACL, I can manage that myself

6) SEO urls not needed, something like (www.site.com/blog/view/1) will do

Theme/template support is not needed as I want to fuse it together with my application's look.

I have searched for something like that, but could find only large CMS like FuelCMS, etc which I think come with alot more features.

Can anyone suggest me something like the above?

Comment: Take a look at Expression Engine from Ellislab. This are the people behind CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you the pyrocms. Its one of the best CMS which can fulfull most of the requirement which you want to do. you can get it from here http://www.pyrocms.com/

Comment: If I am not wrong PyroCMS is a full featured CMS, a full application in itself bundled with alot of features. I dont want most of the features, I just want a proper text editor, categories, pages & posts and proper sanitizing of inputs.